# What's the TypeScript "type" of the input to the match() function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, types, typescript

[Javascript String Match function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

From the above documentation I see that the input to the String.prototype.match() function is "regexp". It's obviously not a string. What is its type?

In TypeScript how can I declare the input variable?

```
regex:regexp = ^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$
```

The above obviously throws an error as regexp is not a recognized type. How can I fix it?

Comment: var regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/g
    regex.test(your variable) // This will output the true and false result

Comment: @Deep What's the type definition of that? How can I declare that in Typescript? something like regex:regexp = ...

Comment: [In the official declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1650-L1660), the argument can be a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or `string`.

Comment: Also, note that [RegExp literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#RegExp_literals) are delimited with slashes (used similar to quotes for string literals) – `/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/`.

Comment: You don't need to specify the type, since the value will provide that (as long as you enclose it in slashes). FYI, the type of the argument to match is going to be `RegExp | string`.

Answer (score 9):

You can look at the type information in `lib.d.ts`:

```
/**
  * Matches a string with a regular expression, and returns an array containing the results of that search.
  * @param regexp A variable name or string literal containing the regular expression pattern and flags.
  */
match(regexp: string): RegExpMatchArray;

/**
  * Matches a string with a regular expression, and returns an array containing the results of that search.
  * @param regexp A regular expression object that contains the regular expression pattern and applicable flags.
  */
match(regexp: RegExp): RegExpMatchArray;
```

You can see that the type for a regular expression is `RegExp`, and there are two definitions for `match`, one taking a string, the other a RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
//inside the class
//this expression is to test valid email

public reg: RegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
```

and then you can test it in your class

```
this.reg.test("expression to test")
```

//out side the class

```
let reg = /^\d+$/;
alert(reg.test("sd")); //will alert false
```

Comment: alert(/^\d+$/.test("sd")); Optionally you can test it without declaring the variable before hand.