# What is the typescript type for the return value of String.prototype.match()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, match

I am writing a regex in javascript

```
const pattern = /S(\d+)E(\d+)/; // get characters inbetween "S" and "D"
const result  = 'SE01E09'.match(pattern);
```

how do i type the result variable?

I have tried a couple of different approaches such as the following to no avail

```
const result: Array<string | number>  = 'SE01E09'.match(pattern);
```

Comment: When type is inferred, you can easily use either your IDE or https://www.typescriptlang.org/play to check the actual outcome. In this case it's `const result: RegExpMatchArray | null`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464168/whats-the-typescript-type-of-the-input-to-the-match-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn how to answer that yourself: you can at any time hover over a value in your IDE and see the inferred type in a tooltip. Here it would be: `RegExpMatchArray | null`.

Then you can go to the definition, for example by Alt + clicking it (it will depend on your IDE). You may need to type it down so that the link is available (in VS Code, no way to Alt + click the tooltip itself), for example:

```js
type R =  RegExpMatchArray;
//        ---------------- now you can Alt + click this
```

Here there are two definitions:

```js
// from lib.es5.d.ts
interface RegExpMatchArray extends Array<string> {
    /**
     * The index of the search at which the result was found.
     */
    index?: number;
    /**
     * A copy of the search string.
     */
    input?: string;
    /**
     * The first match. This will always be present because `null` will be returned if there are no matches.
     */
    0: string;
}

// from lib.es2018.regexp.d.ts
interface RegExpMatchArray {
    groups?: {
        [key: string]: string
    }
}
```

Because of a feature called interface merging, you can expect `RegExpMatchArray` to have both behaviours.

Now you should be able to look up anything.

Comment: great advice on finding the inferred type using the tooltip in my IDE. It seems obvious now and i will be checking there in future

Answer (score 1):

It would be `RegExpMatchArray  | null` .

```
const result: RegExpMatchArray  | null  = 'SE01E09'.match(pattern);
```

More details can be found [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.regexpmatcharray.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code would have worked with the array type if you had also considered the possible null return value in case you don't have a match:

```
const result: Array<string | number> | null  = 'SE01E09'.match(pattern);
```

You don't need to be explicit about the inferred type RegExpMatchArray. And since you only get back an array of strings in case of a match, this would be enough:

```
const result: string[] | null  = 'SE01E09'.match(/\d+/g);
```